# What is setuptool's alternative to (the deprecated) distutils `strtobool`?

Tags: python, argparse, setuptools, distutils

I am migrating to Python 3.12, and finally have to remove the last `distutils` dependency.

I am using `from distutils.util import strtobool` to enforce that command-line arguments via `argparse` are in fact bool, properly taking care of `NaN` vs. `False` vs. `True`, like so:

```
arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
arg_parser.add_argument("-r", "--rebuild_all", type=lambda x: bool(strtobool(x)), default=True)
```

So this question is actually twofold:

- What would be an alternative to the deprecated `strtobool`?
- Alternatively: What would be an even better solution to enforce 'any string' to be interpreted as `bool`, in a safe way (e.g., to parse args)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using argparse's [`BooleanOptionalAction`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/argparse.py#L889)? This is documented in [the argparse docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), but not in a way that provides me with a useful link.

That would look like:

```
arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
arg_parser.add_argument("-r", "--rebuild-all", action=argparse.BooleanOptionalAction, default=True)
```

And it would allow you to pass either `--rebuild-all` or `--no-rebuild-all`. This gets you an option that can be either true or false, but without the hassle of having to parse a string into a boolean value.

Comment: It seems to be not so much documented as "publicly acknowledged to exist" :)

Comment: thanks! using `action=...` is indeed quite an improvement vs the `type=lambda` in my original post! I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: No, it's actually documented, right there in the official documentation, in the [`action`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) section. It's listed as "New in 3.9".

Comment: this a convenience extension of the long  existing `action='store_true'1

Comment: Yes, that's correct! In this situation (a default true option that you want to be able to disable) it leads to generally better semantics than, say, using `store_true` and an explicit `no-rebuild-all` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this alternative:

```
$ pip install str2bool
```

**https://github.com/symonsoft/str2bool**

> Convert string to boolean. Library recognizes "yes", "true", "y", "t", "1" as True, and "no", "false", "n", "f", "0" as False. Case insensitive.

Comment: thanks! quite a 1:1 match with the original `str2bool` and exhaustive in terms of what it maps from string to bool. given the other proposed answer to unequivocally use a boolean `action=` flag, which really enforces a default, unless exactly matching the boolean opposite, that approach is probably a lot safer than using the (also very old) str2bool package (and thus the even better answer)